# Can I specify a CodeSniffer standard as a dev composer dependency?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpcodesniffer

Say I have two or three projects, and they all use different PHP CodeSniffer standards (custom made).

I'd like to be able to include them as `require-dev` dependencies with Composer, so that when spinning up a project repository they will be installed along with PHPUnit and my other dev requirements.

Currently I have all of the standards on my machine's global `phpcs` standards folder and I'm telling each project which standard to use via a `phpcs.xml` configuration file in the project root.

Can I specify a path to the standard, so that it can be installed and used via composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an additional path for `phpcs` to look for standards in using the [`installed_paths` setting](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Configuration-Options#setting-the-installed-standard-paths). Here's an example `phpcs.xml` configuration:

```
<?xml verison="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyProject">
  <description>My cool project, using a custom PHPCS standard</description>
  <rule ref="MyCoolStandard" />
  <config name="installed_paths" value="vendor/myvendorhere" />
</ruleset>
```

Then assuming your custom PHPCS standard has a file structure like this:

```
+ MyCoolStandard
  - Sniffs
    - Classes
      - MyClassSniff.php
  - ruleset.xml
```

You can add a basic `composer.json` file to it and give it a name. An important part here is that you will need to tell it to install into a path that *matches the standard name* - or more simply just **name the package as your standard** (note: needs to match `ruleset.xml` in the standard, case included):

```
{
    "name": "myvendorhere/MyCoolStandard",
    "description": "My cool PHPCS standard",
    "require": {}
}
```

Now you can just include it as a VCS repository in your project:

```
# Project: composer.json
...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:myvendorhere/myreponame.git"
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "myvendorhere/MyCoolStandard": "dev-master"
    }
...
```

---

### TL;DR:

- Use the `installed_paths` CodeSniffer configuration setting to specify your composer's vendor path (up until the folder named after your standard) as a standards path
- In your standard's repository, name the composer package after the standard (case sensitive). It must be the same as the name you use in your `ruleset.xml` so that `phpcs` can find it, otherwise you'll get errors saying it couldn't befound.
- Include your custom standard as [a VCS repo](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) in the project's composer config (or a better way...!)